# Counterexample to Nullstellensatz (Problem 1.32 in Fulton's book)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Problem 1.32 in Fulton's Algebraic Geometry asks to show that the following corollary to the Nullstellensatz is false if $k$ is not an algebraically closed field:

If $I$ is a radical ideal in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, then $I(V(I)) = I$. So there is a one-to-one correspondence between radical ideals and algebraic sets.

It is easy to find a counterexample to show that the usual correspondence between radical ideals and algebraic sets (given by the maps $V$ and $I$ in Fulton's book) fails to be one-to-one if $k={\mathbb R}$. But strictly speaking,  if I wanted to show that the second sentence in the corollary is false, I would need to prove that there is no other map whatsoever that could set up such a correspondence. This seems quite difficult to me, and maybe not even true.

Comment: One needs to be more precise about the nature of the "correspondence". If one simply means a set bijection, for example, then probably there are lots of one-to-one correspondences. Presumably, though, one means a correspondence that respects some structure of the sets of radical ideals and subvarieties.

Comment: I agree. There is no precise definition of what a "correspondence" is in the book and normally one would take that to mean any bijection, but it seems that is not what the author had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a one-to-one correspondence never exists when $k$ is finite. In this case, there are finitely many algebraic sets since they are subsets of $\mathbf A^n_k = k^n$, but there exist infinitely many radical ideals (e.g. there is one for each irreducible polynomial over $k$).

I'm afraid that's the only source of examples. When $k$ is infinite, on one hand, there exist $|k|$ algebraic sets because every point is itself an algebraic set and $|k^n| = |k|$. On the other hand, since $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is Noetherian with Krull dimension equal to $n$ and there are at least $|k|$ radical ideals corresponding to the points in $k^n$ , we see that there are also exactly $|k|$ radical ideals. So, if by one-to-one correspondence you just mean any bijection, there will be (infinitely many) one-to-one correspondences between radical ideals of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and algebraic sets.